# Why initialization of const char array member incompatible in constructor initializer?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a Test class with overloaded constructor. Initializing const char array member by string literals work fine. But, initialization by const char * gives error -

> error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char*’ to ‘const
>   char [25]’

```
class Test
{
    const char d_arr[25];
public:
    Test() : d_arr("Test Class") {}
    Test(const char * arr) : d_arr(arr) {}
};
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You can copy the C-terminated string data over using an `n` version of the `strcpy` function. Or just a loop. Decide what to do when the string is too long to fit, e.g., truncate it, or throw an exception.

Comment: More generally just use `std::string` instead of raw arrays and pointers and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a pointer to an array, which is not allowed.

i.e. You cannot do following:

```
const char *arr = "ABC";
const char d_arr[25] = arr;
```

What you need to do is copy the chars manually i.e. something like:

```
Test(const char * arr) {
 size_t index = 0;
 if (arr) {
  while (arr[index] && index < 24) {
   d_arr[index] = arr[index];
   ++index;
  }
 }
 d_arr[index] = 0;
}
```

That all said, as said in comments, its better to use std::string.

Comment: This is not compiling with `const char d_arr[25]`.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o I missed constness. It can't work for const array member .